# How to avoid attribute redeclarations in Rails ActiveRecord subclasses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord

Given the following code:

```
class BaseType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :a, :type
end

class SubType < BaseType
  attr_accessible :b
end
```

I want the attribute `a` to be accessible in `BaseType`, and the attributes `a` and `b` to be accessible in `SubType` without having to declare `a` again in `SubType`. Single table inheritance doesn't help in this case, or at least I couldn't figure it out. What other solutions could be applied?

**Update:**

After the comment from timpone this is how I tested the code above:

Creating the models via:

```
rails g model BaseType a:string type:string
rails g model SubType b:string
```

Changing the superclass in sub_type.rb from `ActiveRecord::Base` to `BaseType`. After migrating I tried to create a new SubType instance in the rails console and got the following error:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > SubType.create(:b => "A")
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: b
```

Why is that so?

Comment: You shouldn't have to declare a again. Did you test it out in rails console? Or you might need to rephrase question

Comment: It makes perfect sense that you're getting the ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError. The attribute 'b' is no longer in your SubType class because you're now subclassing BaseType and not ActiveRecord::Base. That attribute is still in your sub_types table of course but has become inaccessible.

Comment: You may want to better define what you mean when you say you want an attribute to be "accessible". Are you conflating that with attr_accessible?

Comment: I guess I am. How else can I define `SubType` which inherits `a` from `BaseType` so I can create a new instance by `SubType.create(:a => "A", :b => "B")`?

Comment: I solved my issue using polymorphic associations as described here http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations